# Playlist with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html5-audio

I have a playlist with two songs, but every time I play it only the first one is played. I can't figure out the problem. I'm trying to create a quiz every time the user clicks on the wrong answer the two songs are played.

My code:

```
$(stage).append('<div id="play"><audio id="bg_audio">
    <source src="../Voices/check_answer.ogg"></source>
    <source src="../Voices/good.ogg"></source></audio>
    </div>'); 
$('.pix').click(function() {
    if(questionLock==false) {
        if(this.id!=rnd) {
            $('#bg_audio').get(0).play();
        } else {
            questionLock=true;  
            setTimeout(function(){changeQuestion()},1000);
            $('.displayed', stage).addClass('hidden');
        }
    }})
}
```

Comment: With the code you provided we "can't figure out the problem" either. Please post a code that can be tested. An JSFiddle would be a nice extra too.

Comment: second that, can you try to break down exactly what part of the code we should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood how [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) tag works. It is meant to provide *the same* audio file in different formats, and not to create a list of audio files to play.

If you want to only play an audio, without displaying controls, you can use the [`Audio` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) instead of creating HTML elements and appending them to the page.

```js
// Take a list of files as arguments.
const playList = (...list) => {
  // Stop recursion when the list is empty.
  if (list.length === 0) return Promise.resolve()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create a new Audio element from the first item on the list.
    const audio = new Audio(list.shift())
    // Resolve the promise after the file ends playing.
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => resolve(...list))
    // Reject the promise if the file fails to load.
    audio.addEventListener('error', () => reject('Resource failed to load.'))
    // Play the audio.
    audio.play()
  // Continue playing the rest of list recursively.
  }).then(playList)
}

// For simplicity, play the same file twice.
playList(
  'http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.mp3'
 ,'http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.mp3'
)
```